# Powershell Cmd and Option at runtime

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Let me write this example: we are in a deploying process where we want call a command runtime (Get-SPFeature for example), and this command accepts some options that you want change during the process where you should deploy some pkgs.
Some features have to be installed in a Web Scope, other in Site Scope, other in the WebApplication scope.

The idea is write only one Function that can help you to choice where enable the feature after a check:

```
function EnableFeatures ($features, $where, $url, $logFile)
```

The $features variable is an Array with the list of features to enable. The $url variable is where this feature should be.
We need the $where variable to check if the feature is enable or not before try to enable it in that scope:

```
Get-SPFeature -Identity "my feature" -Webapplication/Site/Web "my url"
```

What I would like to do is exec my EnableFeatures function with the variables I need and do this check.

How can I do that?

Comment: How do you expect to call your `EnableFeatures` function? I don't understand your usage of the `$where` parameter

Comment: EnableFeatures "name of feature", "-Site", "my url", $logFile

Answer (score 2):

I think you can only use hash table [splatting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts.aspx) because you are using named parameters in variables.

So this would result in:

`Get-SPFeature -Identity $feature @{$where=$url}`

or

`Get-SPFeature @{Identity=$feature; $where=$url}`

Oh... and you also could do:

`Invoke-Expression "Get-SPFeature -Identity $feature $where $url"`

But it might be slow for your needs.

Comment: just for knowledge, how can I use an option that is without value... like the -Force option?

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio `-Force` is a `switch`: it can take `$true` or `$false`. So `@{Force=$true}` should work with splatting. With `Invoke-Expression` it seems trivial. Also consider clarifying your initial question as most people don't understand it - given the number of downvotes.

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio It should, unless you use PowerShell v1.0. Splatting is a v2 feature.